# How to avoid decrypted decoded query string params to be encoded again with HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a uri with query string params that I encrypt and encode. Then I decode and decrypt. The decrypted decoded one has same params as original ones.

However, when I get the uri query string params using `uri.ParseQueryString()`, the decrypted, decoded params gets encoded again due to inbuild encoding of this method.

Also this happens only when I use non-english foreign characters. If I fix this, then special characters (+, %) gets encoded twice so + becomes space.

Not sure how to retain a query param like `A你好B+c de.txt` to this form. It becomes this `A你好B+c de.txt`. Or `A%u4f60%u597dB+c de.txt` when + is fixed.

HOw can I get original one `A你好B+c de.txt` back?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are misusing the query parameters. It seems like what you should really be using is post data, and encrypting the contents of that before you send it.